# How to apply sed script only to headers of email?

Tags: sed, newline

This script strips the timezone from an email's Date fields:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf
s/(^Date: (Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat),.*[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]) \+0900$/\1/i
```

However, I don't want the timezone stripped if a date appears in the body of the email. <strike>How can I get sed to quit after a double newline is encountered (signaling the end of the email header fields)?</strike> **How can I apply substitutions only to the header of an email? Is this possible in sed?** An awk solution would also be acceptable.

**update:**

I figured out how to quit sed like I wanted by matching an empty line:

```
/^$/q
```

However, I didn't really want to quit because the body of the email is not printed, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can do this using the branch functionality and have the branch do normal printing.  `/^$/b x`

```
#!/bin/sed -rf
x
/^MAGICTOKEN$/b body
x
s/(^Foo: bar).*/\1/i
p
s/^$/MAGICTOKEN/
/^MAGICTOKEN$/x
d

: body
x
p
d
```

Of course if I were doing this for real I would use perl.